# Apache-Zeppelin 0.7 build from source failed at zeppelin-server

Tags: apache-spark, docker, ubuntu-14.04, apache-zeppelin

i'am stuck on a weird bug when installing Apache Zeppelin 0.7.0 in a Docker container running under Ubuntu 14.04 with a Spark on Local Mode.

I build Zeppelin with this command (as root) :

```
mvn clean package -U -X -DskipTests -Pspark-2.0 -Dspark.version=2.0.2 -Phadoop-2.7 -Pyarn -Ppyspark -Psparkr -Pr -Pscala-2.11
```

The build Bug when reaching zeppelin-server telling me :

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-zengine:jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Leading to the following warning :

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "spark-2.0" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "hadoop-2.7" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "yarn" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "pyspark" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[WARNING] The requested profile "sparkr" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

For finally having this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project zeppelin-server: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-server:jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-zengine:jar:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots  (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
```

Thanks in advance for helping me to figure this out.

*PS: Sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to run following command in the `zeppelin home` not in the `zeppelin-server` directory?

`mvn package -DskipTests -Dfile=zeppelin-zengine-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 1):

I see similar issue here: http://apache-zeppelin-users-incubating-mailing-list.75479.x6.nabble.com/Writing-New-Interpreter-td2742.html

Can you try if the following fix the problem:

```
mvn package -Dfile=zeppelin-zengine-0.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for you're fast response, Sadly when i try to run this command in the zeppelin-server directory i get the same warning about the POM and the same error about the dependencies